# Is there an easy way to replicate the functionality of this site using jQuery/Mootools/PHP?

Tags: jquery, mootools

I'd like to create something similar to the shirt-designer feature found on this site:

http://www.tailorstore.au.com/tailor-made-shirts

(it would be for a completely different business type, I just like the way that this particular site works).

I can see that it's built using MooTools, but beyond that I can't find the specific scripts that are making the site work the way it does.

Is there a pre-made framework/plugin that I can use to build similar webapp for myself? Ideally I'd like to start with something that's ready-made and then mess around and tinker with it until it looks the way I want it to, as I personally find this is the best and easiest way to learn.

EDIT: I'll be a bit more specific about what I'm trying to do. I want to have similar 'options' on the left that relate to their appearance (height, weight, skin colour, eye colour, hair colour, that sort've thing), and an updating 'avatar' on the right which reflects whatever changes the user has made. (I suppose this would be very similar to creating a "Mii" avatar on the Wii, or creating a customiseable character in many RPGs) Then I want the be able to use this data later on to recommend products based on the options the user has selected.

Is there a way that this could be built using PHP/jQuery, and if so, where would be the best place to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially i think you would need to use layered divs with abs positioning. Then simply add and remove divs with  the png's of the options. However that means you would have to store the coords of each option for each product it can be used on. Tou could also store an image of each product rendered with all possible option combinations which would increase performance. But then you have to create tooling to output those unless you want to make them manually.

Im sure you could do i and overall Id imagine it would be more tedious than it would be difficult to implement.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I don't have anywhere near as many options as the tailor-store designer though, so thankfully it wouldn't be THAT difficult to create a pre-built design for each possible option. If I went down this path, what would be the best way to store the user selections? I would want to recall them after they press a "submit" button, and then have an if/else statement that says "if question1variable = 1, create "<div>recommend product x</div>"; else if question1variable=2, create "<div>recommend product y</div> and so on. jQuery? Php? I'm new here! :)

Comment: You will want to use JS to switch the frontend display - so jQuery is a possibility though you could use an js lib/framework or even raw js to accomplish this. If you have all the possible combination for given product as static images then you dont necessarily need php... you can just use js to figure out what file to load on the product div. if you need to persist the choices between requests then you will need to use a serverside language like php to store the data in the session... although i suppose you could use a cookie with js instead...

Comment: IF you need to save the data indefinitely then youll need some kind of datastore like a db or flat file or something, and then youll need to write to it at some point. when to do that and what type of store to use really depends on the system youre building/

Comment: That's great mate, thanks a lot for your help, much appreciated. I'm struggling with the dilemma of learning how to do all of this myself or just paying someone who already knows how to do it to do it for me. At this stage I'll go down the PHP/jQuery route and investigate further. Thanks again.